# What is a random eigenfunction on the hyperbolic plane?

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

Is there an (invariant under isometries) notion of a random eigenfunction on the hyperbolic plane, for a given eigenvalue?

It is a reference request because the answer is probably positive and I even have some ideas about how such a thing can be constructed. (This question was inspired by the well known quantum unique ergodicity conjecture but is not really related to it.)